# System menu hover state fix in Nordic theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes

Here is what my system menu when an item is hovered upon looks like. I need help with how to fix the hover state color to make the text visible when it is hovered on.

System menu of Pop!_OS using Nordic theme when an item is hovered on:

[image: system menu of popos using nordic theme when an item is hovered on]

Comment: This site is for Ubuntu and its (official) flavors. Pop!_OS is not Ubuntu, Sorry, but your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Alright, thanks